# Jquery scroll function looping

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple jquery plugin made with few options to show an element. Main options show a div based on time delay or scroll function. Time delay works fine but scroll keeps looping - switching checkbox state on/off.

I've came so far: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pj5cp0ss/2/)

```
(function($) {

$.fn.testing = function( options ) {

    // Settings
    var settings = $.extend({
        delay           : null,
        delayTime       : null,
        scrolling       : null,
        scrollDist      : null
    }, options);

    return this.each( function() {
        var self = this;

        // Timeout
        setTimeout(function (){
           $(self).prop('checked', settings.delay);
        }, settings.delayTime);

        // Scroll
       if ($(window).scrollTop() > settings.scrollDist) {
          $(this).prop('checked', settings.scrolling);
       };

    });

}

}(jQuery));

// Plugin invoke
$(window).on("load resize scroll",function(){
    $('#testInput').testing({
        delay             : false,
        delayTime         : null,
        scrolling         : true,
        scrollDist        : 20,
    });
});
```

During the compiling i probably missed something, but can't see what.
Would be great if function stopped when scroll event triggers and element shows up without this looping.

Comment: see this https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/pj5cp0ss/3/  .. Is that what you want?

Comment: Thanks Mohamed. Actually i want the element to stay visible when scroll occurs. In your fiddle it hides (uncheckes the checkbox) after scrolling up. Also would like to keep scroll and time delay options separated so i can pick only one, either scroll or setTimeout function.

Answer (score 0):

It seems reloading on scroll and resize is rerunning the function and causing errors. Try it without the plugin invoke window functions wrapper:

```
// Plugin invoke
//$(window).on("load resize scroll",function(){
    $('#testInput').testing({
        delay             : false,
        delayTime         : null,
        scrolling         : true,
        scrollDist        : 20,
    });
//});
```

Comment: Nope, disables the plugin completely.

Comment: Its strange, doesn't work on here but does on my jFiddle. This could be of some use: https://jsfiddle.net/pj5cp0ss/2/

Comment: That fiddle is actually original from my question :)